# Celery task result persistent strategy

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I have a web server, a rabbitMQ server and two task processing servers in the system. Using Celery to manage the tasks. The web server needs to query the status of the tasks. Based on Celery's doc, I can choose database as result backend. In this case, should I set a database for the web server and another database for each task processing server or use one database for all these 3 servers?

I also tried to use RPC as the backend, but each time the web server restarts, the status of tasks are "PENDING" after querying from AsyncResult. This is my configuration of Celery.

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = True
CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = None
```

Anyone can help? Thanks!